# how to remove single quote ' character in mysql text field?

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT count(email_details.id) as total_emails,
       email_titles.* 
  FROM email_details 
  LEFT JOIN email_titles ON email_details.email_title = email_titles.title 
 GROUP BY email_details.email_title 
 ORDER BY email_titles.id ASC
```

Now my problem is  `email_details.email_title` is blob field and `email_titles.title` is text field, 
both field has a data with `’` chracter say "this month’s video" when i runs this query without `left join` the row having `’` chracter does not retrieve,
if i put left join then it retrieves only first table data.
how to solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: share your query code.

Comment: Share your code and test data or remove `php` and `codeigniter` tags

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is just a tool that tries to do its best to help you work with databases. It doesn't show you the content of `BLOB` fields but this doesn't mean anything. Does your code (`PHP` or whatever language you are using) encounter any problem working with that value? I didn't use it in the last 5 years but as far as I remember (and the blue color of the `BLOB` text should hint you) the `[BLOB]` texts are links and clicking on one of them you can see the content of the field for that particular row.

Comment: you right but i does not want to just show value i want to retrieve it on basis of joins. i achieved that and added my answer below. thanks for @all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by my self,
i have modified join code like this

```
LEFT JOIN `email_titles` ON CONVERT( email_details.email_title
USING utf8 ) = CONVERT( email_titles.title
USING utf8 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to join on something other than those large chunks of text or if that is not possible, make sure that the same text is stored in the same way on both tables.

If that isn't possible either, you need to convert the blob into text for the join, possibly also convert the varchar into char. Something like this

```
SELECT count(email_details.id) as total_emails,
       email_titles.* 
  FROM email_details 
  LEFT JOIN email_titles 
    ON email_details.email_title = CAST(email_titles.title AS char(100) CHARACTER SET utf8) 
 GROUP BY email_details.email_title 
 ORDER BY email_titles.id ASC
```